# Does the Rainbow Servant give new spells per day starting at level 2, or at level 1?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells, multi-classing, prestige-class

I want to make a Beguiler and take a dip into Rainbow Servant. However, in the Rainbow Servant class it says this:

> When a new rainbow servant level is gained, the character gains new
>   spells per day as if she had also gained a level in whatever
>   spellcasting class in which she could cast 3rd-level arcane spells
>   before she added the prestige class. She does not, however, gain any
>   other benefit a character of that class would have gained (improved
>   chance of controlling or rebuking undead, wild shape ability, and so
>   on). This essentially means that she adds the level of rainbow servant
>   to the level of whatever other spellcasting class the character has,
>   then determines spells per day accordingly. ....

Then in the chart, beginning at the second level of Rainbow Servant, it says under "Spells per Day":

> +1 level of arcane spellcasting class

So if I take 1 level of Rainbow Servant do I get more spells per day based on my base class or not?

Comment: That's three different questions; you should ask the Beguiler-6-downsides and Beguiler-Good-domain-spontaneous questions separately. As far as the main question, I suspect some errata may have gotten involved.

Answer (score 4):

You gain spellcasting every lv.

There is conflict between the text explaining spell casting progression and the table of the class explaining spell casting progression. Luckily, WoTC covered this.

#### DMG Dungeon Master's Guide v.3.5 Errata

> Errata Rule: Primary Sources
> When you find a disagreement between two D&D rules
> sources, unless an official errata file says otherwise, the
> primary source is correct. **One example of a
> primary/secondary source is text taking precedence over a
> table entry**

And since the text says you get spell casting every lv, you gain spell casting every lv.

Comment: While technically accurate, I'm certain the asker would appreciate the controversy surrounding the class be addressed (or, at least, an acknowledgement that there *is* some controversy).

Comment: @HeyICanChan Honestly, personally I have seen little controversy on this point.

Comment: @KRyan Huh. Okay. Maybe it's just me, but in most discussion I've seen, rainbow servant inevitably raises [something like this](http://www.giantitp.com/forums/showthread.php?75556-Rainbow-Servant-how-good#11).